# Ubercart checkout page country select overrules my attached javascript file

Tags: javascript, ubercart

I have an ubercart checkout page with different payment methods for different countries. So when you change your country, it should show a different set of payment options. This is done by a jquery script, which fires if the Country input field changes. And this script works, as I can see when debugging the script with firebug/chrome developper kit.

However, shortly after that, ubercart decides to rebuild the whole payment methods checkout pane, and thus the jquery script becomes obsolete. How can I let my jquery script run after or again when the whole payment methods list is 'rebuild' or altered?

An example can be found at http://curvefever.com/cart/add/e-p1034_q1-ipremium3months?destination=cart/checkout

Best regards,

Geert

Module code:
I use it as follows (in uc_moneybookers_form_alter):

```
if ($form_id == 'uc_cart_checkout_form') {
    $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'uc_moneybookers') . '/CheckPaymentOptions.js' => array(
        'type' => 'file',
      ),
    );
  }
```

Jquery:

```
(function ($) {
var CheckPaymentOptions = CheckPaymentOptions || {};

CheckPaymentOptions.init = function() {
setDefaultOptions();
handleAddress("b");

$("#edit-panes-billing-billing-country").change(function() {
  handleAddress('b');
});

$("#edit-panes-billing-billing-address-select").change(function() {
  setTimeout("handleAddress('b')", 100);
});

$("#edit-panes-billing-copy-address").click(function() {
  var t = setTimeout("doIfChecked()", 100);
}); 
};

function handleAddress(paneFrom) {
if (paneFrom == "b") {

  var country = parseInt($("#edit-panes-billing-billing-country").val());
} else {
  var country = parseInt($("#edit-panes-delivery-delivery-country").val());
}
setDefaultOptions();
showForCountry(country);
};

function doIfChecked() {
var checked = $("#edit-panes-billing-copy-address").attr("checked");
if (checked) {
  handleAddress("d");
} else {
  handleAddress("b");
}
};

function setDefaultOptions() {
$('input[id*=moneybookers]').parent('div').hide();
$('input[id$=moneybookers]').parent('div').show();
$('input[id*=moneybookers-cc]').parent('div').show();
};

function showForCountry(num) {
switch(num) {
  case 276:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-sft]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-did]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-gir]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 56:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-sft]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 250:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-sft]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-gcb]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 528:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-sft]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-idl]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 756:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-sft]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 826:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-sft]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-vsd]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-mae]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-slo]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-vse]').parent('div').show();
   break;
  case 40:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-sft]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-eps]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-mae]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 208:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-dnk]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 702:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-ent]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 100:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-epy]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 246:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-so2]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 752:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-ebt]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 380:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-psp]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-csi]').parent('div').show();
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-vse]').parent('div').show();
   break;
  case 616:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-pwy]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 372:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-lsr]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 616:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-pwy]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 36:
  case 554:
  case 710:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-pli]').parent('div').show();
    break;
  case 724:
    $('input[id*=moneybookers-vse]').parent('div').show();
    break;
}
};


$(document).ready(CheckPaymentOptions.init);



}(jQuery));
```

Comment: If you are using behaviors properly, it should work the way you want. But we cannot tell without source codes.

Comment: I added source code to the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made one mistake. See [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) - you should make your code a behavior. That way, it will be run for every new element that appears on page. Don't forget to use `context` where needed. Using `$(document).ready()` directly is strongly discouraged for compatibility reasons, and your case looks like perfect example of a problems that may arise when you do.

Comment: Thank you alot for putting me on the right track. I tmade me solve this puzzle. I found a nice article on how to use Drupal Behaviors and what they are: http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/drupal-behaviors-quick-how . 
Some additional things that I had to change: A behaviour is (among other things) a super document.ready . Functions are left outside of the behaviour.

Comment: @Geert well, I couldn't repost whole manual here. I'm glad I posted enough for you to know what's wrong and make it all right :)